# How do I remove an entry from Windows Boot Manager through Lubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mbr

So I have a laptop that I got through work: it had one half of the HDD partitioned to their own version of Windows Enterprise (so no cmd unless you have admin rights) and the other half partitioned to be Windows 7 Home (so I'm basically free to do what I want with this partition). I just replaced the home partition with Lubuntu, but now I'm faced with a small, but annoying problem: if i select Windows in Grub it will go to the Windows Boot Manager, as it still thinks that there's a partition for Win7 Home. The only way to stop this second screen from coming up is to remove the Home entry from the MBR in Windows.

So, the question I'm asking is would it be possible to rewrite the MBR so that it went straight to the Work partition instead of giving me a choice between Work and Home when I select Windows in Grub WITHOUT actually using Windows (again, no cmd or admin rights there), ie inside Lubuntu? Or is the only option to somehow reinstall the Home partition, remove itself from the MBR and then remove the whole partition back in Lubuntu?

Thanks in advance